# variable name count is displayed in different color in codeblocks

Tags: c++, codeblocks

I am using codeblocks for compiling C source files.
I noticed that variable name count is displayed in green color (default color for reserved words). Any reason? Or is this could be a bug in codeblocks?
Here is the image:

[image: Code Blocks image]

Comment: Well, I don't know if this is the reason, but there is a function called `std::count` in `<algorithm>` that counts the number of occurrences of an element in an iterator range.

Comment: Do you have `using namespace std;` in your code? Then it picks up the [`std::count`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/count) function.